# Error passing a lambda as default argument

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lambda

The code below compiles fine, until I uncomment the line: `lambda();`. Why does it compile if I don't use the function relying on the default argument, but when I try to use the default argument, it doesn't compile anymore?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{   
    static auto lambdaDefaultParameter = []() // must be static, otherwise I get the error that a local variable can't be a default parameter
    {
        std::cout << "default\n";
    };

    // trying a lambda that takes another lambda as parameter
    auto lambda = [](auto&& f = lambdaDefaultParameter)
    {
        f();
    };

    lambda([]() {std::cout << "test\n"; }); // ok
    //lambda(); // error
}
```

Comment: Why are you using move-semantics here?

Comment: Why should I use const&?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `auto` is having some trouble. Specifying the type explicitly works on MSVC. g++ still doesn't compile it, because if thinks a static lambda is a local variable. MSVC only thinks it's a local variable when I don't use the static keyword in `lambdaDefaultParameter`.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    static auto lambdaDefaultParameter = []() // must be static, otherwise I get the error that a local variable can't be a default /parameter
    {
        std::cout << "default\n";
    };

    // trying a lambda that takes another lambda as parameter
    auto lambda = [](void(*f)() = lambdaDefaultParameter) // ok
    //auto lambda = [](auto f = lambdaDefaultParameter) // error
    {
        f();
    };

    lambda([]() {std::cout << "test\n"; }); // ok
    lambda(); // ok
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot capture something with automatic storage duration as a default parameter.  Either move the lambda into global scope, or capture it as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main()
{   
    auto lambdaDefaultParameter = []()
    {
        std::cout << "default\n";
    };

    auto lambda = [](std::function<void()> f =
                     [lambdaDefaultParameter](){ lambdaDefaultParameter(); }
                    )
    {
        f();
    };

    lambda([]() {std::cout << "test\n"; });
    lambda();
}
```

Output:

```
test
default
```

Comment: How do you do it without std::function?

Comment: A *capturing* lambda can't be assigned to a plain function pointer, so you can't use, for instance, `auto lambda = [](void (*f)() = [lambdaDefaultParameter](){ lambdaDefaultParameter(); })`, thus `std::function` is needed. A *non-capturing* lambda can work without `std::function`, eg: `auto lambda = [](void (*f)() = [](){ lambdaDefaultParameter(); })` but then you are back to the original problem again.